# Как сделать резиновый блок, стоящий рядом со статическим в строке

Tags: css3, веб-программирование, html

Использую блочную вёрстку.
Код HTML:

```
<div class="field-bottom-left left ico1">
    <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State" value="State" />
</div>
<div class="field-bottom-right right ico1">
    <input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="Zip" value="Zip" />
</div>
```

Код CSS:

```
section .field-bottom-left {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    width: 50%;
}
section .field-bottom-right {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
    margin-top: -1px;
    width: 100px;
}
input {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0;
}
```

Что мне нужно добиться:
блоки стоят в одной строке, тот блок, что справа, имеет фиксированную ширину в `100px`,
а блок слева должен растягиваться или сжиматься в зависимости от того, как пользователь повернул телефон - `portrait` или `landscape`.
В общем, нужно блок, стоящий слева, автоматически сжимать и растягивать, у меня не получается, надеюсь, что кто-нибудь подскажет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фиксированному блоку задаете float:right, а тянущемуся - правый отступ в ширину фиксированного блока. При этом в потоке сперва должен идти фиксированный блок, а потом - тянущийся.
Пример можете посмотреть [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/8f3recgr/).